# NFS, Quotas & root not liking each other

Tags: linux, centos, quota

I have a few CentOS servers i would like to backup nightly.

I have created a NFS server with the following mounts :

1. /backup/server1
2. /backup/server2
3. /backup/server3

On the CentOS servers i have mounted the nfs share as /backup and everything works fine with read and writes.

The issue is that the files sent over NFS are always ending up with root or nobody permissions (if all_root_squash is set).

How can i properly set quotas when my NFS clients all are using the same UID and the same root user?

Comment: That is perfect! with anonuid i can simply map them to my local users and enforce quotas! Thank you so much HBrujin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your [`exports`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/exports) file you can use the `anonuid` and `anongid` to explicitly set the uid and gid of the anonymous account.

This option is especially useful in combination with the `all_squash` option which maps all uids and gids to the anonymous user,  which you can then use to enforce your quota:

```
/backup/server1       server1(rw,all_squash,anonuid=1001,anongid=1001)
/backup/server2       server2(rw,all_squash,anonuid=1002,anongid=1002)
```

Comment: That is perfect! with anonuid i can simply map them to my local users and enforce quotas! Thank you so much HBrujin –